# Selenium WebDriver find_elements methods don't find empty elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver with python, with ChromeDriver.

When trying to find th elements in a thead, find_elements method only find 3 of them, while there are 4 in the DOM. One of them is not found, it turns out it's an empty element :

```html
<table>
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th class="data-table-selection-icon" scope="col"></th>
             <th scope="col">
                <div class="bx--table-header-label">Whatever</div>
             </th>
             <th scope="col">
                <div class="bx--table-header-label">Whatever2</div>
             </th>
             <th scope="col">
                <div class="bx--table-header-label">Whatever3</div>
             </th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody >
          <tr>
             <td width="16">
                <svg><!-- some svg --></svg>
             </td>
             <td>Whatever</td>
             <td>Whatever2</td>
             <td>Whatever3</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

I've used the following find_elements calls :

```
tr = thead.find_element_by_tag_name("tr")
table_headers = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("th")  
table_headers2 = tr.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"th")  
table_headers3 = tr.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//th")  
table_headers4 = tr.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//node()[contains(@scope,'col')]")  
table_headers5 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//thead/tr/*")
```

They're all finding only 3 elements.

Comment: can you confirm the url? I cannot reproduce it on string only, with chromedriver/selenium

Comment: No I'm sorry, it's not a public site.

Comment: find a similar public url (with a table with an empty <th>) and post it here.

Comment: I put the table into a snippet on the question. You can probably browse that page with selenium, click the "Run code snippet" button. And it will display the table. Not sure though, this SO puts that into an iframe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: [One more thing](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES):

Selenium 4.3.0

- Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)

---

Not sure how kosher this is, but let's give it a try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.relative_locator import locate_with
import pandas as pd
import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73068196/selenium-webdriver-find-elements-methods-dont-find-empty-elements#73068196'
browser.get(url)
button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Run code snippet')]")
button.click()
iframe = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@name='sif2']")))
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
t.sleep(1)
# table_head = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "thead").get_attribute("outerHTML")
table_head = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "thead")
th_cells = table_head.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "th")
for x in range(len(th_cells)):
    print('th:', x, th_cells[x].get_attribute("outerHTML"))
browser.quit()
```

This returns 4  elements:

```
th: 0 <th class="data-table-selection-icon" scope="col"></th>
th: 1 <th scope="col">
                <div class="bx--table-header-label">Whatever</div>
             </th>
th: 2 <th scope="col">
                <div class="bx--table-header-label">Whatever2</div>
             </th>
th: 3 <th scope="col">
                <div class="bx--table-header-label">Whatever3</div>
             </th>
```

So .. your original table must be different, or I'm missing something in your code.

Comment: Thanks for testing that! Obviously it works for you. I'm pretty sure there's something wrong on my side but I fail to see what it is.

Comment: Maybe ... replace `find_element_by_*` in your code with `.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, ...)` and try and use `.get_attribute("outerHTML")`?

Comment: So I updated to selenium 4.3.0 and used find_element functions all around, no difference. 
I desperately added a time.sleep(10) before getting the th elements and it solved the issue. 
I suppose the empty TH is initialized by some JavaScript that's a bit slow. And selenium gets the 3 other TH before the 4th is added to the DOM...

Comment: Welcome. Why did you not add WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.TAG_NAME, "th"))?